# Why AJAX response broken <form> tag

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax, forms

I have 2 simple synchronous AJAX requests:

```
iDialog.LoadContent(url).done(
    function()
    {
        content = iDialog.content;

        $.ajax({
            method: "POST",
            url: iDialog.router,
            data: { content: content }
        }).done(function(response) {
            //do some stuff..
        });
    }
);
```

**LoadContent:**

```
LoadContent: function(url)
{
    if (url === "undefined")
        return;

    return $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: url,
        data: {},
        success: function(html)
        {
            iDialog.content = html;
            var iDialogEvent = new CustomEvent("iDialogContentLoaded");
            window.dispatchEvent(iDialogEvent);
        }
    });
},
```

Where `content` is a simple form `<form></form>`. `response` is the answer from the server and it should be the same form, but instead of it I received a broken tag `<fo rm=""></fo>`. Interesting that `console.log(content)` shows correct `<form></form>`, it seems the issue somewhere in second query. Never faced this odd problem before.

**Server side:**

```
ob_end_clean();
echo $_REQUEST["content"];
die();
```

Shall I send HTML tags in another way? What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `if (url === "undefined") return;` is a bug, it will cause an error if url is ever undefined.

Comment: Check network tab of console and examine the XHR. you might get clue there. another guess is  do `data: { content: encodeURIComponent(content) }` in your `done` part.